# Am I on right path to simplifying php code block?

Tags: php, mysql

Fairly new to php and following e commerce tutorials. When exploring a way to resolve a problem I had with a php code block, I came upon a post another person had with the same code block.
https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/272404-help-problem-with-some-line-of-codes/
 The post suggested a way to simplify the code.

Original code block:

```
   <?php
if (isset($_POST ['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST ['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0; 
    if (!isset ($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION ["cart_array"])<1){
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array (0=> array("item_id"=> $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    }  else {
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++; 
            while(list($key,$value)=each($each_item)){
            if ($key== "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                array_splice ($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1,1, array(array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=> $each_item['quantity']+1)));
                $wasFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if($wasFound==false) {
        array_push ($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id"=> $pid, "quantity" => 1));    
        }
    }
    header("Location: cart.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

This was the suggested simplified code block and an explanation of what to do after changing code. I am unsure how to implement the the part suggested after the code block.

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    // add (+1) item to cart
    $pid = (int)$_POST['pid']; // cast as integer
    // valid pids are > 0
    if($pid > 0){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$pid])){
    // item is not in the cart, add it with quantity = 1
    $_SESSION['cart_array'][$pid] = array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1); // I left the array in the cart the same, but it could also be simplified so that it is only the quantity, since the item_id is now the cart array index
    } else {
    // item is in the cart, increment quantity
    $_SESSION['cart_array'][$pid]['quantity']++;
    }
    }
    header("location: cart.php");
    exit();
    }
```

To get the details for the cart items, you need to run ONE query that gets all of them at the same time (putting a query inside of a loop is a resource killer.) For the definition of the cart that I have suggested, you can use array_keys to get all the item id's. You would then implode those into a comma separated list and put them into an IN() comparison in the WHERE clause in a query to get all the matching rows at once. 
Edited by PFMaBiSmAd, 27 December 2012 - 02:05 PM.

This is what I am considering adding to the code block:

```
if  ($result = print_r(array_keys('cart_array',$pid))) {
$comma_seperated = implode("," $result);

// then use use $comma_seperated in query where needed later in annother code block?
}
```

Am I on the right path?

Comment: You might have better luck over on codereview.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks aynber. Is there an easy way to migrate it to code review?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. You can try flagging for a moderator, or just copy/paste.

Comment: This post was also posted on codereview.stackexchange as aynber suggested. There I got an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was provided by Mike Brant in codereview.stackexchange. This is how I would extract the keys to be used in query.

$pidsInCart = array_keys($_SESSION['cart_array']);

Answer (score 0):

Seems good to me - maybe you should add an check, if the session contains cart_array. And very important - indent your code! The one your provided isn't very readable..

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = (int)$_POST['pid'];
    if($pid > 0){
        if (!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart_array'] = [];
        }

        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$pid])){
            $_SESSION['cart_array'][$pid] = ["quantity" => 1];
        } else {
            $_SESSION['cart_array'][$pid]['quantity']++;
        }
    }
    header("location: cart.php");
    exit();
}
```